Filter into two different collections
(let [ truthys (filter #(filter-func %) coll)
       falsys (filter #(not filter-func %) coll)]

This code traverves coll twice and applys filter-func twice to each element. I was wondering, is there a way to filter coll into both truthys and falsys in just one go?

Nit-picking: #(f %) is just f and #(not (f %)) (note, you missed
the parens around the call to filter-func) could be written as
(complement f).

(let [{truhys true, falsys false}
      (group-by filter-func coll)]
  ...)


This is a particularly good idea since it only visits each item in the collection once (where calling filter twice goes over the collection twice)

i would advice, (group-by (comp boolean filter-func) coll). otherwise it can lead to some very nasty bugs. (like: this example doesn't consider nil return from the filter function, it operates on true and false rather then truthy and falsey, which is more idiomatic). like (filter identity [1 false 3 nil]) => (1 3), but in the case of this response it would give truthys = nil, falsys = [false]. instead of truthys = [1,3], falsys = [false, nil], which is how clojure filtering behaves
